# update from angular 10 to 13. Now error add 'CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' implemented fix but still broken

Tags: node.js, angular, npm, schema, web-component

Here are an example for a few errors

```
                    ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    Error occurs in the template of component ShochatactivestreamviewShellComponent.


Error: src/app/money_makers/shochat_guts/shochat_content_creator_components/active-stream-dashboard/shochatactivestreamview-shell/shochatactivestreamview-shell.component.html:16:40 - error NG8002: Can't bind to 'twiliochattoken' since it isn't a known property of 'app-shochat-contentcreator-chat'.
1. If 'app-shochat-contentcreator-chat' is an Angular component and it has 'twiliochattoken' input, then verify that it is part of this module.
2. If 'app-shochat-contentcreator-chat' is a Web Component then add 'CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component to suppress this message.
3. To allow any property add 'NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component.

16                                        [twiliochattoken]="contentcreatorchattoken"></app-shochat-contentcreator-chat>
                                          ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

  src/app/money_makers/shochat_guts/shochat_content_creator_components/active-stream-dashboard/shochatactivestreamview-shell/shochatactivestreamview-shell.component.ts:10:16
    10   templateUrl: './shochatactivestreamview-shell.component.html',
                      ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    Error occurs in the template of component ShochatactivestreamviewShellComponent.


Error: src/app/money_makers/shochat_guts/shochat_content_creator_components/stream-setup/shochatcontentcreatorview-shell/shochatcontentcreatorview-shell.component.html:1:1 - error NG8001: 'app-content-creator-shochat-no-have-stream-key' is not a known element:
1. If 'app-content-creator-shochat-no-have-stream-key' is an Angular component, then verify that it is part of this module.
2. If 'app-content-creator-shochat-no-have-stream-key' is a Web Component then add 'CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component to suppress this message.
```

and then here is my `app.module.ts`

```
 import {CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA, NgModule, NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA} from '@angular/core';

    @NgModule({
      declarations: [
        AppComponent,
    LandingpageComponent,
    FooterComponent,
    HeaderComponent,
    AboutusComponent,
    Notfound404Component,
    EmailcaptureComponent,
    AdminshellComponent,
    ContentcreatorapprovaladminComponent,
    ContentcreatorverificationComponent,
    ContentcreatorrosterComponent,
    ContentcreatorgutsShellComponent,
    UserprofileComponent,
    AffiliatelinksComponent,
    SignupComponent,
    ContentcreatorsetupComponent,
    ContentcreatorverificationrequestsadminComponent,
    ApprovedcontentcreatoradminComponent,
    ContentcreatorhomepageComponent,
    VerifiedcontentcreatoradminComponent,
    AllcreatorsoftypeComponent,
    ContentfeedsubscribeviewComponent,
    ContentcreatordashboardComponent,
    DashboardcreatorfeedsettingsComponent,
    ContentcreatorcontentpostcreateComponent,
    MonitarydependancysignupComponent,
    MonitarysignupSiteuserCreatorcreateshellpageComponent,
    UserServicesShellComponent,
    ContentfeedlikesandtipsComponent,
    SubscribedusetoubsubscribeComponent,
    ShochatcontentcreatorviewShellComponent,
    ContentCreatorShochatNoHaveStreamKeyComponent,
    ContentCreatorShochatHasStreamKeyStartStreamComponent,
    ShochatactivestreamviewShellComponent,
    ShochatactivestreamlivevideoComponent,
    ShochatContentcreatorChatComponent,
    ShochatDisplayToUserComponentComponent,
    ShochatUserChatComponent,
    UserSetChatnameComponent,
    ShochatUserLivevideoComponent,
    ShochatUserShochatsDisplayComponent,
    ShochatUserVideoCallComponent,
    ShochatVideoChatComponent,
    ShochatUserVideoCallActualComponent,
    ShochattimerComponent,
    UserconsomablepreviewComponent,
    CreditcardorloginaddneeedComponent,
    ContentcreatorendshochatreviewComponent,
    UserendshochatreviewComponent,
    UserFavLikesPurchaesesComponent,
    CreatorstatsComponent,
    CreatortypeindexComponent,
    ShochatshowpreviewComponent,
    EmailverifedrefreshuserloginComponent,
    ContentfeedpostsComponent,
    ContentcreatorintrovideodashboardComponent,
    ShochatEncodingHowtoComponent,
    SubscribingplaceholderComponent,
    ContentcreatorcategoriesadminComponent,
    ModeratecreatorpostsadminComponent,
    ContentfeedpostcommentsComponent,
  ],
  imports: [
      BrowserModule,
      RouterModule,
      FontAwesomeModule,
      RecaptchaV3Module,
      FormsModule,
      HttpClientModule,
      AppRoutingModule,
      VgCoreModule,
      NgxAudioPlayerModule,
      NgbModule
      ],
      imports: [
          BrowserModule,
          RouterModule,
          
          NgxStripeModule.forRoot(<removed>),
          AuthModule.forRoot({
              domain: environment.auth0_domain,
              clientId: environment.auth0_client_id,
              redirectUri: window.location.origin,
              audience: '<removed>',
    
              // The AuthHttpInterceptor configuration
              httpInterceptor: {
                  allowedList: [
                    {
                      uri: 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/*',
                      tokenOptions: {
                        audience: '<removed>'
                      }
                    },
                      {
                          uri: '<removed>',
                          tokenOptions: {
                              audience: '<removed>'
                          }
                      }
    
                  ],
              },
          }),
          VgOverlayPlayModule,
          VgControlsModule,
          VgStreamingModule,
          NgxAudioPlayerModule,
          BrowserAnimationsModule
    
      ],
      schemas: [ NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA, CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA ],
      providers: [Addemailtomarketinglistservice,
        { provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS, useClass: AuthHttpInterceptor, multi: true },
        {provide: RECAPTCHA_V3_SITE_KEY, useValue: environment.recaptcha_site_key },
      Googlerecaptchaservice, AuthService, HidecomponentService, S3Service, InternalStripeService,
      TwilioConversationService, TwilioVideogrouproomService, MediaDeviceManagementService,
      TwilioSyncService, CreateContentCommService, PreviewpostsetService],
      bootstrap: [AppComponent]
    })
```

notice that the `schemas` attribute has been added

it is important to note I have tried this fix with both no errors and custom elements individually added to schema as well as both added to schema

What is really weird is I check so many stackoverflow posts, blog posts, and the alike and this is the fix.

but every time I run `ng serve` after making this fix in my `app.moudle.ts` file I still get the error above. Is there something I am clearly doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. The fix for me was to make sure that the `CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA` was declared in the same module as the component I was trying to use the web component in.

I had initially been adding `CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA` to my `AppModule` but the component I wanted to use it in was in a submodule called `PlatformModule`. Once I moved the declaration there then it all worked.

Looking at your code it seems like you're already doing that but I'll leave this here in case it helps anyone else.